# How to Make Layout support Multiple Screen Size (Responsive)

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using the following code for my about page but the content alters according to the screen size and orientation please help here is the code for

## about.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#493F0B" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAboutHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F5F6D4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:text="@string/about_title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvabout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvAboutHeader"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#CDE855"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:text="@string/about_info1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvabout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvabout1"
    android:background="#ABC921"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:text="@string/about_info2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvabout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvabout2"
    android:background="#BEDB39"
    android:text="@string/about_info3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I considered using scroll view but i am getting errors if needed here is my

## About.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class About extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#493F0B" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAboutHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F5F6D4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="@string/about_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvabout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvAboutHeader"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#CDE855"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="@string/about_info1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvabout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvabout1"
            android:background="#ABC921"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="@string/about_info2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvabout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvabout2"
            android:background="#BEDB39"
            android:text="@string/about_info3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

try this

Comment: @NishalKulkarni this is not Responsive, but it is a non-responsive, which is contrary to your question.

Comment: @jyoon I think will work because it has relative layout with warpcontent height which will adjust with the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Make different Layouts for different Screen Sizes. Read the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) first.
All you need to do is create a new folder in `res/` called `layout-sw<number>dp` where  would be replaced with the screen dimension. For example, a 7-inch Tablet would use `layout-sw600dp` and a 10-inch tablet would use `layout-sw720dp`, copy the layout inside here, and rearrange it so it would be responsive.

For different orientations, you can put `-land` or `-port` after the name of the layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's because your using a relative layout and sometimes when using it two widgits can merge.  Try using a linear layout that should solve your problem if that's your problem.